# d3js line graph showing a tangent

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3js to render a time series data. Everything works fine but the graph shows up like below. Anyone know if this is a know issue or something else? I checked the data and there are no error that make it draw a loop.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is being filled black by default. The css for the `path` object should be:

```
.curve {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

(Of course, you need to use a selector that actually finds the curve. ".curve" is just a placeholder.)

You can alternately do this in code:

```
...
.append(path)
.attr("d", path)
.style("fill", "none")
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("stroke-width", "2px");
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. Adding attributes to path worked.